# Converting from Time to Laplace and back to Time again?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to convert something from time domain to Laplace then back to time, but it isn't working. Here is a simple way to illustrate, with force (F), mass (m), acceleration (a), velocity (V), and position (y):

$F(t) = m a(t)$

$F(s) = m a(s)$

$F(s) = m (sV(s) - v0)$

$F(s) = m (s^{2}y(s) - sy(0) - y'(0))$, if y0=0, then:

$F(s) = ms^{2}y(s)-mv(0)$

$y(s) = \frac{F(s)+mv(0)}{ms^{2}}$

Then given: $\frac{1}{s^{2}} = t$ from [here](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html):

$y(t) = \frac{(F(t)+mv(0)) * t}{m}$

Only that doesn't actually make sense, because then you are saying:

$displacement = \frac{(force + momentum) * time}{mass}$

The units don't work out.

So where was the error in the above to explain the problem?

Comment: In your fourth line you have a mistake. The last term should be $y'(0)$. But beyond that, you have another issue. The inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s^2}$ is not $t$, it is the ramp function. The dirac delta is the second derivative of the ramp. Convolution with a delta retrieves the original function, convolution with a unit step yields the function's antiderivative, and subsequently convolution with the ramp function gives the antiderivative of the antiderivative. You'll find that this has the correct units.

Comment: A way you could've seen this even without knowing the bit of knowledge of the ramp function is that the units for $F \star t$ is not force $\times$ time. A convolution would look like $\int F(t-\tau)\tau d\tau$ which is in units of $F\times \tau \times d\tau =$ force $\times$ time $\times$ time.

Comment: Thanks Ninad. So for my line 4, I see my mistake. It should be: 
$F(s) = m (s^{2}y(s) - sy(0) - y'(0))$ which is: 
$F(s) = m (s^{2}y(s) - sy(0) - v(0))$, right? As for my second error, why does this page list $\frac{1}{s^{2}} = t $ if it is not so? https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html Is there a better reference for what I'm supposed to substitute? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, please read my second comment to make sure it makes sense. Second, it says so in the table right there. Notice on the far left it says ramp.

Comment: Thanks Ninad but I still don't understand why the table says $ramp = \frac{1}{s^{2}} = t$. I have used that table for other conversions to the time domain and they worked okay. You are saying that substitution is wrong? Or are you saying I am not understanding what "t" represents? I thought "t" in time based equations was just time in seconds.

Comment: What is the ramp function?

Comment: I don't know anything other than everything tells me $\frac{1}{s^2} = t$. Even the symbolab inverse Laplace calculator says this: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bs%5E%7B2%7D%7D Why does everything say this is what it is if you're telling me it's not?

Comment: Answer my question, don't go off on irrelevant tangents.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't have any degree in math. I am learning this as I go on my own. I don't know how it is "irrelevant" that every reference I find says $\frac{1}{s^{2}} = t$ and you are telling me it is not. Why do all these references say it is if it is not? Can you please explain? This is confusing. Are these references referring to a different concept than you are? They all say the same thing. $\frac{1}{s^{2}} = t$

Comment: I do not have a degree in math, either :) But I cannot help you if are unwilling to do some research. I 100% believe you are not helpless, you are a more than capable individual. Stop panicking. If you don't know what something is, what should you do? Keep in mind I already know the answer, so don't just link me to some website. Just answer me in your own words.